# Level creation and ArrayList problems

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, lwjgl

I am trying to make a game with lwjgl/Java, but when it comes to the level creation i have had multiple problems with trying to put my Entities in a ArrayList. I am later on going to create levels in txt files and I'll store them there instead, but for now this is the only option I've got
I am getting a NullPointerException when i try to run the game.

```
public class Level {

int levels = 10;

Player player;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Entity>[] entities = (ArrayList<Entity>[]) new ArrayList[50];
Enemy[] enemies = new Enemy[20];        //This it later going to be added in the entities arrayList
                        //The reason its a normal array is so that it would work with collision detection



//Pre-init of the levels should be done here
public Level(){

    player = new Player(90, 40);

    for(int i = 0; i <= levels; i++)
    createLevels(i);
}

//Collision check
public void update(){
    //Checking collision against enemies
    for(int i = 0; i <= levels; i++ ){
    Utilities.util.isColliding(player, enemies[i]);
    }
}


/*  LEVEL CREATION
 * 
 * The first thing that is going to be in the "level editor" text file
 * is which level the items are going to be added to. Like so:
 *      - level 0
 * 
 * The entity adding is later going to be added in a text file as so:
 *      - Group entity xPos yPos Width Height
 *      - enemies enemy 60 60, 200, 100
 * 
 * The player postition is the first two numbers in txt file,
 * Player is also the last item that should be added to entities
 */

public void createLevels(int level){

    System.out.println("Level " + level + " is being created.");

    if(level == 0){


        addEntity(player, level);

        addEnemy(new Wall(40, 40, 200, 322), level);


        //Adding all enemies to entities
        for(int i = 0; i <= enemies.length; i++){
        entities[level].add(enemies[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Level " + level + " was created!");

}

private void addEntity(Entity ent, int level){
    entities[level].add(ent);
}

private void addEnemy(Enemy nmy, int level){
    enemies[level] = nmy;
}
```

I have had this problem for quite some time and i would love to get some help with it. I know it may be a very noobish question but please help me out!

Here is the NullPointerException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sontvedt.engine.Level.addEntity(Level.java:119)
at com.sontvedt.engine.Level.createLevels(Level.java:59)
at com.sontvedt.engine.Level.<init>(Level.java:27)
at com.sontvedt.engine.Game.<init>(Game.java:14)
at com.sontvedt.engine.Window.initGame(Window.java:42)
at com.sontvedt.engine.Window.init(Window.java:36)
at com.sontvedt.engine.Window.main(Window.java:24)
```

Line 119 is in addEntity method creation

Comment: So, what is this famous problem?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having then? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Yes, sorry about forgetting such a major part of the problem. I am getting a nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0):

The exception happens at the following line:

```
entities[level].add(ent);
```

So, either `entities` is null, or `entities[level]` is null.

`entities` can not be null, since it's initialized here:

```
ArrayList<Entity>[] entities = (ArrayList<Entity>[]) new ArrayList[50];
```

So, the only possible reason is that `entities[level]`is null. Is there somewhere in the code where a new ArrayList is created and stored in the `entities` array? I can't find any.

Comment: No but i add one and one entity to one specific part of the ArrayList entities. So for instance if i am going to add a player to the level i can type: entities[0].add(new Player(54, 54))  And this should add a new entity to level 0 AKA entities[0]

Comment: And what my answer says is that `entities[0]` is null, because you have never executed `entities[0] = new ArrayList<>()` before. An array is filled with null by default. Not with empty ArrayLists.